# Standard French to Canadian French sentence for consumer GPS product

Tags: traduction, québec

I've generated a somewhat generic French translation for the following sentence, but I'd like some feedback from native Canadian French speakers to know if the sentence sounds like a natural, comprehensible Canadian French sentence or if any part of the sentence could be improved for a Canadian French-speaking audience:

> Find your way easily and capture the unexpected with a GPS navigation and dashboard camera all in one.

> Trouvez facilement votre chemin et capturez l'inattendu avec une caméra de navigation et de tableau de bord GPS tout en un.

Comment: This kind of sentence would not be different on one side or other of the Atlantic. But I think the end of the sentence is wrong in both. Aren't these back-up cameras and GPS navigation??

Comment: La question est compliquée par le fait qu'on a des mots bien usuels et un style réclame pour désigner une réalité technique. La [_caméra de tableau de bord_](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26542598) c'est du vocab. technique pour un type de caméra embarquée. Là on tente de faire un apport de l'idée de navigation GPS sur le mot composé et on a de la difficulté avec la cohérence. La traduction où l'on sépare la navigation de GPS fait douter rétroact. de l'apport de _GPS navigation_ dans la phrase en langue anglaise, à savoir _GPS navigation camera_ est-il possible ? Merci.

Comment: If speaking about a device acting both as a GPS and a dashboard camera. I would then say "Trouvez facilement votre chemin et capturez l'inattendu grâce à un GPS avec caméra de tableau de bord intégrée", or "grâce à une caméra de tableau de bord avec GPS intégré", depending on the device self looking more like a GPS or a camera

Answer (score 4):

Bonjour,

As a native Canadian French speaker, I suggest you to keep your own translation. Your translation is very good.

The expression "caméra embarquée " makes no sense to us.